# NextJs custom server

Tags: next.js

I've set a [custom server from the example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/master/examples/custom-server-typescript) but, my question is...

Can the server code access the NextJs code?

I mean, NextJs is built with webpack, therefore packed in its own context, so if I want to initialize something (let's say, database, logging system, etc.) in the server **before** NextJs has started, and then access it from NextJs... is it possible? I don't see how unless server code and NextJs code are in the same bundle, is it?

Yes, I guess there are some *hacks* that can be used, like importing files in runtime with `__non_webpack_require__`... but that seems like a hack (?) and only in one direction.

Any other better option?

Comment: Any reason not to use serverless? You can still initialize things (databases, logging) inside API routes. I know it's not exactly your question, but it will likely help you build a more scalable application.

Comment: is it better to have one logger + once db + whatever instances per NextJs Page? even if you have a lot of them? instead of just one shared object for all pages?

Comment: Once you initialize your database, you can then use it inside API routes to communicate with your database. It's not "per page" because it's the separation of the frontend and the backend. Any page can call this API route to then retrieve data.

Here's some more info on using databases in a serverless world: https://vercel.com/docs/solutions/databases

Comment: well, it literally says "Because traditional relational databases have low concurrent connection limits, we should try to maximize connection re-use." and recommends to use a connection pooling... which is basically what I was trying to create but not serverless... it looks to me like the serverless approach just complicates more the implementation

Comment: NextJS allows you to create a custom expressJS server (https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server). This along with a service manager like pm2 (https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) will do the trick.

Comment: @JonathanDsouza well, that's exactly the first line of the question, so... ???

Answer (score 0):

If you use SSR in NextJS, you can access to APIs before rendering.

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31493633)

Answer (score 0):

If you export a function called getServerSideProps (Server-Side Rendering) from a page, Next.js will pre-render this page on each request using the data returned by getServerSideProps.

It fetches your data upon a user requesting your website everytime.
Thatmeans no matter what you build first on your server. Next.js will fetch for it every time. The comment above me sent the correct link. https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props

TO view all data fetching techniques from next.js visit: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/overview

PLease comment back to this to see if this helped, or if we missunderstood the question, so that we can help solve this issue, or if you resolved it. happy coding!